# В чем полезность сервисов?

Tags: angular2

Начал по понемногу осваивать angular2. Столкнулся в нем с сервисами. В статье про них написано не очень много. Написано что это классы работы с данными и они ни какой связи с представлениями не имеют. Вот у меня и появились сомнения в их полезности.

Вопрос к знатокам angular, часто ли встречаются веб-приложения таких масштабов чтоб не сильно сложную работу с небольшим количеством данных надо было перекладывать на вот такие сервисы (неужели тот же JSON нельзя переработать в компоненте), это же не бэкенд где работа с файлами и бд идет.

Comment: Ну во первых сервисы внедряються как зависимость, и не создают каждый раз новые класы. Во вторых это повзволяет не повторять код. И в третьих нужно разделять модель контроллер и представление. Всегда нужно создавать сервисы, даже если сервис 1 и в нем 1 функция.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю:

1. Как уже писали, сервисы нужны для разделения логики. У Angular'а нет файлов и бд, но у него есть бэкенд с которым надо работать и вот тут то Вам и понадобятся сервисы.
2. С учётом того, что сервис Singleton - удобно в нём размещать глобальные переменные доступные в любом месте (межкомпонентное взаимодействие).

Comment: 1. ангуляр работает с тем что уже пришло из бекэнда. какой смысл обрабатывать то что уже обработано.

2. Глобальные переменные независимы сами по себе и их удобно использовать в любых случаях.

а вот в разделении логики есть смысл тут я с вами согласен, но и ведь можно писать обычные функции и помещать их в отдельный файл (модуль) вместо сервиса.

Comment: Если помещать функцию в отдельный файл, то формально вы получите тоже самое, что и создав сервис. Просто будет "некрасиво", не "канонично". Angular просто пытается формализовать, разделить логику, ввести чуточку упорядоченности, туда, где её нет.

Comment: И возвращаясь к глобальным переменным. Канонично создавать переменные глобальные через сервисы и инжектировать их в каждый контроллер,  в котором их использовать есть необходимость.